# How to delete Firefox desktop shortcut that keeps reappearing

Tags: firefox, windows-11

I noticed a new desktop shortcut to open Firefox when Firefox updated to version maybe 104 or around it. I keep my desktop empty so this is very noticeable. I deleted the shortcut but the next time I opened my computer the shortcut reappeared.

I have gone through Firefox settings but didn't find any settings related to desktop shortcut.

How do I remove this Firefox desktop shortcut for good?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out somebody else [experienced the same thing in 2012](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/934662). The shortcut is actually in "all users folders" in older windows. In Windows 11 the shortcut is in `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`, or "This PC" > C > Users > Public > "Public Desktop". Deleting the shortcut in it will delete the shortcut for good.

Comment: I deleted the shortcut from Public Desktop, and that removed it from my user desktop, but a few days later the shortcut appeared in Public Desktop again, also causing it to re-appear on my user desktop.

Comment: The path you provided is empty.